# Accepting multiple user inputs in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C that accepts user input in either of these formats:

1. string, int
2. string, int, int or float

Some examples of valid inputs:

1. Susan 5
2. David 10 24
3. Sarah 6 7.5

How do I accomplish this in C?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int num1;
    int num2;

    if(scanf("%s %d", name, &num1) != 2 || scanf("%s %d %d", name, &num1, &num2) != 3)
    {
            printf("Failure");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Pass");
    }
}
```

This intends to print "Failure" if there is invalid user input and "Pass" if the user input is valid. The issue here is this code forces me to enter both formats in order to print "Pass." So if I input "Susan 5" I would have to input "David 10 24" in order to print "Pass" even though I have an or conditional and not an and conditional, which I don't understand. What I want is once I input "Susan 5" and hit enter, my program should be able to print "Pass."

Comment: You'll need to read a line of input first into a buffer (using e.g. `getline()`) and then use *`sscanf`* on that buffer instead of `scanf`.

Comment: When you say that the first item always is a "string", do you mean one word? Or could it also consist of two words, such as "John Paul"? In that case, using the `scanf`/`sscanf` format specifier `%s` will not work, as that will only read one word.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The function `getline` is not part of ISO C; it is a platform-specific extension. Note that the question has not been tagged with a specific platform.

Comment: In the case that the user enters a "string" followed by two integers, is it acceptable that you store that second integer as a floating-point number intstead of an integer, because the user is also allowed to enter a floating-point number as the second number?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, the first string must be one word! It is acceptable for the second integer to be stored as a floating point

Comment: `scanf(...) ... || scanf( ...` is not a good pattern.  The first scanf will (probably) consume some data that will not be available to the 2nd scanf.  Unless you are storing the values returned from scanf, it will be difficult to know which data has been consumed, since you won't even really know if the 2nd scanf was executed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are three possible inputs:

One word followed by an integer followed by

1. nothing, or
2. another integer, or
3. a floating-point number.

Since you have stated in the comments section that it is acceptable in case #2 to store the second integer as a floating-point number, we can consider cases #2 and #3 to be the same case.

In the line

```
if(scanf("%s %d", name, &num1) != 2 || scanf("%s %d %d", name, &num1, &num2) != 3)
```

the second `scanf` function call will probably not work, because the first one has already consumed some of the input. Therefore, you should first read one line of input using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and replace the calls to `scanf` with calls to [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int num1;
    double num2;

    char line[100];
    int num_consumed;

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that entire line was read in
    if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "line too large for input buffer!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to convert first two parameters
    if ( sscanf( line, "%9s%d%n", name, &num1, &num_consumed ) != 2 )
    {
        printf( "Failure\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    printf( "Pass\n" );

    //attempt to read third parameter as a floating-point number
    if ( sscanf( line+num_consumed, "%lf", &num2 ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "User entered only one number:\n%d\n", num1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "User entered two numbers:\n%d\n%f\n", num1, num2 );
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

Bad input:

```
Susan David
Failure
```

Only one number as input:

```
Susan 5
Pass
User entered only one number:
5
```

Two integers as input:

```
David 10 24
Pass
User entered two numbers:
10
24.000000
```

One integer and one floating-point number as input:

```
Sarah 6 7.5
Pass
User entered two numbers:
6
7.500000
```

One possible problem with the program is that it does not check why the second `sscanf` failed. For example, it will treat the input

`Susan 5 dslfhksdhfkl`

the same as if the user has simply entered:

`Susan 5`

The question does not state whether the input should print `Failure` in such a case or not. However, meanwhile in the comments section, you have stated that the program should reject input such as the following:

```
Susan 5 ddggghh
David 10 24 dslfhksdhfkl
```

Therefore, in the program below, I have added an additional check in both cases to verify that all remaining characters after the matched characters are [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (there will always at least be a newline character at the end of the line). If not, then the input gets rejected.

In order to determine whether a character is a whitespace character, I use the function [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Here the updated program with these additional checks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//this function will return whether a string consists
//entirely of whitespace characters
bool is_string_whitespace( const char *str )
{
    for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    int num1;
    double num2;

    char line[100], *p;
    int num_consumed;

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that entire line was read in
    if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "line too large for input buffer!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to convert first two parameters
    if ( sscanf( line, "%9s%d%n", name, &num1, &num_consumed ) != 2 )
    {
        printf( "Failure\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    //attempt to read third parameter as a floating-point number
    p = line + num_consumed;
    if ( sscanf( p, "%lf%n", &num2, &num_consumed ) == 1 )
    {
        //verify that all remaining characters are whitespace
        if ( !is_string_whitespace( p+num_consumed ) )
        {
            printf( "Failure" );
            return 0;
        }
        printf( "Pass\n" );
        printf( "User entered two numbers:\n%d\n%f\n", num1, num2 );
    }
    else
    {
        //verify that all remaining characters are whitespace
        if ( !is_string_whitespace( p ) )
        {
            printf( "Failure" );
            return 0;
        }

        printf( "Pass\n" );
        printf( "User entered only one number:\n%d\n", num1 );
    }
}
```

This program now correctly rejects the inputs mentioned above:

```
Susan 5 dslfhksdhfkl
Failure
```

```
David 10 24 dslfhksdhfkl
Failure
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! "Susan 5 ddggghh" will be a failure.

Comment: @brisharpiro: Do you want `David 10 24 dslfhksdhfkl` to also be rejected? In other words, should the program also verify that the user didn't enter additional input into the line, even if the first two numbers are okay?

Comment: Yes, that would also fail. The ONLY valid inputs are <string int> or <string int int/float> hench why in my original code I am only checking for formats "%s %d" or "%s %d %d".

Comment: @brisharpiro: I have now added a second program to my answer which performs the desired input checks.